# Import from CSV (from Excel) to MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, import, import-from-csv

I'm new to databases so I don't really know how is this actually properly called.

Let's say I have a list of PEOPLE that traveled to some LOCATIONS. I've got a table in Excel (which I saved as CSV file) - it's structured like the picture in the attachment.

I want to transfer this to my database.

I've set up a Apache server, MySQL and PHP via XAMPP.

In the database I created I have two tables: LOCATIONS (id, location_name) and PEOPLE (id, person_name). So my best guess is that I need a third table (relation) which will connect those two: VISITED (locations.id, people.id).

My questions are:

1. Is there a name/something for this situation I described?
2. Is there a way to import that CSV file to the VISITED table?
3. Or is there a different (better) way of doing that?

As I stated above, I don't know how is this "situation" called, so, sorry for (probably) not naming the question accordingly.

1) Picture of the excel relation table "people-locations": [link](http://oi57.tinypic.com/3329ij7.jpg)

2) Picture of tables "people" and "locations": [link](http://oi62.tinypic.com/210x3bk.jpg)

Comment: I don't see 'the attachment'.  Your solution of three tables (Locations, People, and Visited) sounds plausible.  Ideally, you'll have three CSV files, one for each table.  If you don't, then you need to show the data you do have and then we can probably give you guidance.

Comment: Sorry Jonathan, I actually forgot to upload the picture. 
As I'm newly registered here, I can just give You the link (until rating of 10 achieved). I edited the OP and put the link in the end. 

I hope You can understand what am I talking about from the pictures above.

Answer (score 1):

The "situation" you refer to is called a many to many relationship. If it is possible that any one person may have visited more than one location then you have a many-to-many relationship.

In order to create a many-to-many relationship between any two tables -- in your case people and locations -- you need a third table to maintain that relationship. You correctly surmised that you'll need a third table that you called Visited.

In terms of imports there are a couple of ways you can do this and it really has to do with the people.id and location.id values.

Version 1:

You can assign id values to locations and people yourself in excel. When you create your mysql table you do so in such a way that you have to assign the people id value yourself. This can be problematic if the set of people is large.

```
create table People (
    id int,
    name varchar(50)
);
```

Version 2:
You instruct mysql to create the id values based on a "sequence."

```
create table People (
    id int not null auto_increment primary_key,
    name varchar(50)
);
```

Some more examples are here: http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/CREATE-TABLE-examples.html

The issue with Version 2 is that you do not know the values of the People.id or the Location.id until after the insert statement into the database has occurred. That makes it difficult for you to do an import into a Visited table because you won't know the id values until after you've done the imports into the other two tables.

You could do the imports to generate the id values and then pull those values back into excel and use a vlookup function to relate the existing names/locations to their newly assigned mysql id values. You'll need to be careful there are no duplicate names in the list.

Having brought the ids back into excel, used vlookup to tie to new ids, you could generate a csv file with the correct ids to import as the many-to-many table Visited.

You should also look at some examples of csv imports into MySQL: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know the name and the logic behind it pretty good - couldn't remember the name until You said it, thanks. I got this: I created two tables in the database: (1) PEOPLE, with fields ID (primary, unique) and NAME, and (2) LOCATIONS, with fields ID primary, unique) and NAME. I know all the ID's from both of the tables, and there are no duplicates. All ID's are already sorted (auto increment). Now I'm stuck at creating the "relation" (vlookup, excel) from those unique ID's. –